# Deadlock when changing first responder from uitextfield to uitextview [iOS 7]

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview, ios7

have a really strange problem here, this did not happen before iOS 7...

i have a uitextfield and uitextview in a form that i created... the problem is that if the user has the textfield as first responder then taps on the uitextview a deadlock happens, memory will increase until the watchdog kills my app..

This does not happen when I change from uitextview to uitextfield

Relevant code:

```
#pragma mark - UITextView Delegate
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}

NSUInteger newLength = [textView.text length] + [text length] - range.length;

return (newLength > 120) ? NO : YES;

}

-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {

if (textView.tag == CreatePlaceElementDescription) {
    self.marker.info = textView.text;
}
else if (textView.tag == CreatePlaceElementAddress) {
    self.marker.address = textView.text;
}
}

#pragma mark - UITextField Delegate
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

if ([string isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}

NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;

//Limit name textfield length
return (newLength > 60) ? NO : YES;
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

if (textField.tag == CreatePlaceElementName) {
    self.marker.name = textField.text;
}

}
```

There is nothing more to this than that...

if i resign first responder first this problem won't happen but it will make the user tap the textview twice and that is undesired..

Also the deadlock happens on textview:didEndEditing, (as if the textview was the one resigning the keyboard not the textfield, textfield:didEndEditing is also called).. textview:didEndEditing should not be called anywhere

it really boggles my mind... any suggestions?

Comment: Any reason i'm being downvoted? please be helpful and at least tell me in which way i'm wrong... i have throughly tested all my app, and this error is really bugging my mind..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got what's the problem

i'm using DaKeyboardControl to adjust views when the keyboard appears... what's odd is that it seems this is broken on iOS 7 when changing first responders (it won't enter the deadlock when only one textview/textfield is present)... i'm opening a BUG report to their githubs while i figure which line is producing this error... when i have it i'll share it on a EDIT with you

EDIT: The problem is on the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification receivers... this notification gets called multiple times... the solution it seems is to use UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification or UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification to perform the change of frame...

I hope this can help someone... don't know if the use of UIKeyboardWillShowNotification will present problems to people not using iOS 7 now

Comment: how did you actually change to use the different notifications using DAKeyboardControl?

Comment: sorry for my late response, here is the .h  http://pastebin.com/xwRE7MCw and here is the .m modified version http://pastebin.com/kzBx7b6r , i give you this because i also added some BOOLeans to know when the keyboard is out using monkey patch, the magic of the notification happens at addKeyboardControl and removeKeyboardControl (the commented lines) greetings!

Answer (score 1):

I just managed to fix it by modifying the method inputKeyboardDidShow in DAKeyboardControl.m like below:

```
- (void)inputKeyboardDidShow
{
    // Grab the keyboard view
    if(self.keyboardActiveInput.inputAccessoryView.superview){
        self.keyboardActiveView = self.keyboardActiveInput.inputAccessoryView.superview;
        self.keyboardActiveView.hidden = NO;
    }

    // If the active keyboard view could not be found (UITextViews...), try again
    if (!self.keyboardActiveView) {
        // Find the first responder on subviews and look re-assign first responder to it
        [self reAssignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```