# Why doesn't text field appear in UIAlertViews in iOS 7?

Tags: ios7

Lately I've noticed that in every app that has a specific text field, say to rename or add a file/folder on one of those code editor apps, the text field fails to show up. 
I've tried two different code editors "JSany" and "Html Writer" (Free & Paid), both had the same problem (see below). Also, I checked both apps on my iPod (running iOS6) and this time the text fields appeared.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xpssn.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZcJ9.png

And some guy ranting about it in the reviews section:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KB41g.png

Could anyone tell me if this is being fixed?

Comment: A much better title and question might be "Why doesn't text field appear in UIAlertViews in iOS 7?".

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549519/unable-to-add-uitextfield-to-uialertview-on-ios7-works-in-ios-6/18549552#18549552

Comment: This should help as well:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934776/deadlock-when-changing-first-responder-from-uitextfield-to-uitextview-ios-7